# Passing hashtable as parameter from bash to pwsh

Tags: bash, powershell-core

Is possible to pass a hashtable as a variable in PowershellCore as a one-liner with Bash interpreter?

I'm trying following:

```bsh
pwsh /path-to/script.ps1 -Param1 ABC -Param2 @{ "key"="value" }
```

With Defined parameters in script:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Param1,
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][hashtable]$Param2
)
...
```

Error message received:

> script.ps1: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter
> 'Param2'. Cannot convert the "@{" value of type "System.String" to
> type "System.Collections.Hashtable".

Is there any way to pass a hashtable in Bash to Powershell? It seems problem is with the `@{` value. Normally in pwsh natively accepted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```bsh
pwsh -c " /path-to/script.ps1 -Param1 ABC -Param2 @{ 'key'='value' } "
```